Questions on the $\hom$ Functor and Free Groups
This question arises while learning about the $\hom$ functor. My algebra background is not that strong, so here is my question:

Let $G$ be a free group, and let $f\colon G \to G$ be a group
homomorphism. Consider the induced group homomorphism $f^*\colon
 \hom(G,\mathbb{Z}_2) \to \hom(G,\mathbb{Z}_2)$.

If $f$ is surjective (resp. injective), is $f^*$ injective (resp.    surjective)?

If $f^*$ is injective (resp. surjective), is $f$  surjective (resp. injective)?

If $\text{im}(f)$ has finite index in    $G$, say $n$, does $\text{im}(f^*)$ have index $n$ in    $\hom(G,\mathbb{Z}_2)$?



My attempt: Suppose $f$ is surjective, and $f^*(\varphi) = \varphi \circ f = 0$ for some $\varphi\colon G \to \mathbb{Z}_2$. Then, for all $g \in G = \text{im}(f)$, $\varphi(g) = 0$, i.e., $\varphi = 0$. Hence, $f^*$ is injective. Conversely, suppose $f^*$ is injective, but $f$ is not surjective. Consider a basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $G$ and an element $g_0 \in \mathcal{B} \setminus \text{im}(f)$. Using the universal property of the free group $G$, define a group homomorphism $\varphi_0\colon G \to \mathbb{Z}_2$ such that $\varphi_0(g_0) = 1$ and $\varphi_0(G \setminus \langle g_0 \rangle) = 0$. Then $f$ sends the non-trivial element $\varphi_0$ of $\hom(G,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ to the trivial element of $\hom(G,\mathbb{Z}_2)$, a contradiction. Hence, $f$ is surjective if and only if $f^*$ is injective.

I believe there is a counter-example to $f$ injective $\Rightarrow$ $f^$ surjective. Take the free group on one generator, i.e. $\Bbb{Z}$, and take $f:\Bbb{Z}\xrightarrow{\cdot 2}\Bbb{Z}$ to be multiplication by $2$. This is clearly injective. Then $\text{Hom}(\Bbb{Z},\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}) = \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$, but $f^$ is the zero map, thus not surjective.

A notational issue: the induced group homomorphism is a pullback function; in other words, $\hom( \cdot, \mathbb Z_2)$ is a contravariant functor. So the appropriate notation is $f^$, not $f_$.

From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: "A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."

The third statement is false in most of the cases, even if $G = \mathbb{Z}$.
Assume for simplicity that $G$ is finitely generated, say generated by $k$ elements, then by the index formula, a subgroup $H$ of $G$ of finite index $n$ is necessarily a free group generated by $n(k - 1) + 1$ elements. If $f : G \rightarrow G$ is a morphism with $[\mathrm{im}(f):G] = n$, then $\mathrm{im}(f)$ is generated by exatly $n(k - 1) + 1$, but it is also generated by $k$ elements (the $f(x)$ for $x$ in a minimal set of generators of $G$). Therefore, we must have $n(k - 1) + 1 \leqslant k$ i.e. $(n - 1)(k - 1) \leqslant 0$. This implies $k \in \{0,1\}$ or $n = 1$. The other situations are impossible.
If $k = 0$, $G$ is trivial and your claim is trivially true. If $k = 1$, $G = \mathbb{Z}$ and $f$ is the multipliation by $n$ (or $-n$, it doesn't change anything). In this case, $f^* : \hom(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \hom(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ is the multiplication by $n$ thus $f^* = \mathrm{id}$ if $n$ is odd, $f^* = 0$ if $n$ is even. In the first case, $\mathrm{im}(f^*)$ has index $1$ and in the second one $\mathrm{im}(f^*)$ has index $2$.
If $n = 1$, as you showed, $f^*$ is injective but we have no reason to believe that $\mathrm{im}(f^*)$ has index $1$ (it would mean $f^*$ surjective).
